# Visual studio not respecting code format settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Under Settings, I've disabled all "Place open brace on new line" for everything. It works as I expect when I write my own code (it gets formatted just as in the preview-window under Settings).

However, when for example double clicking a button - thus letting VS add some code - or when using Edit -> Advanced -> Format document, VS screws everything up as if all those open brace-settings where checked.

How do I tell VS that I never ever want an opening brace on a single line alone?

[image]
[image]

Comment: VS is just attempting to get you to write c# as it was intended. Seriously, now, you could reset the user profile and see if that helps

Comment: This is a fresh install of VS, never used the program before. How would a profile reset help?

Comment: Can you press Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D or go to Edit > Advanced > Format Document? This should apply set preferences to the current document

Comment: @Neele: Already tried that menu option (see second paragraph in my post).

Comment: @bos ah, I've missed that. Strange - when I change my options to the ones you've selected in your screenshot it's working for me just as expected

Comment: @Neele: Which version? I use 15.5.3.

Comment: @bos I'm using 15.1

Comment: *boggle* That's even more confusing.